# Counting the number of occurrences of a number starting with the same first digit, then second digit, etc

Tags: r

If I have various numbers in an array e.g. 13239, 23248, 42232, 12134, 24255- I want to count how many of these numbers all start with the first digit "1" (for example in this case, 2 of these numbers have "1" as the first digit), and then how many start with first digit "2", and then moving on to how many of these numbers start with the second digit "1", and "2" and so forth.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Nbe.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to wrap your code into code tags `{}` button in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

We can extract the first digit with `substr` and take the frequency with `table`

```
table(substr(v1, 1, 1))
```

For finding the frequency of numbers that start with 1

```
sum(substr(v1, 1, 1) == 1)
```

---

For finding the frequency count at each digit

```
i1 <- max(nchar(v1))
lapply(seq_len(i1), function(i) table(substr(v1, i, i)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(13239, 23248, 42232, 12134, 24255)
```

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity, you can also use stringi package.

```
install.packages("stringi");
library(stringi);
v1 <- c(13239, 23248, 42232, 12134, 24255);

# Starts with 1
stri_startswith_fixed(v1,"1");

# Starts with 2
stri_startswith_fixed(v1,"2");

#To get count
sum(stri_startswith_fixed(v1,"2"))
```